# Как передать данные из БД в родительский шаблон base.html на Django?

Tags: django

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу передать данные из БД в шаблон, от которого наследую блоки, то есть в шаблон base.html. Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

views.py

```
def base(request):
dep = Departament.objects.order_by('id')
return render(request,'main/base.html', {'dep': dep})
```

base.html

```
<ul>
   {% if dep %}
      {% for el in dep %}
           <li><a href="#">{{ el.name }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
      <li><a href="#">Нет записей</a></li>
   {% endif %}
             
</ul>
```

Comment: Что не так с этим кодом?

Comment: Данные не выводятся в шаблон. Видимо не идут туда, но я решил проблему с этим. Я в urls.py не подключил это. Теперь образовалась новая проблема, конфликт index и base, изучаю данную ошибку.

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.base, name='base'), 
path('', views.index, name='index'),
]